# unable to display the image meta value as background

Tags: theme-development

I want to use meta url as background image.But the fact that I do not want to show "background-image:url('_')" this way because if my meta value is empty.What I thought to end up in this way.

```
$bgimage= get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'settings_image', true );
< div style="<?php echo 'background-image: url(".wp_get_attachment_url( $bgimage )")';?>">
```

I think this is best way since I do not want to put extra conditional block here.Did I make mistake in catenation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very slight one, see below :)

```
$bgimage= get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'settings_image', true ); ?>
< div style="<?php echo 'background-image: url('.wp_get_attachment_url( $bgimage ).')';?>">
```